# What is -z in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" || [ "${3:-}" ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 <username> <password>" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

I want to understand what we mean by `-z "$1"` and `"${3:-}"` in the code. 
Please also help me understand `>&2` in the code.

Comment: `help test | grep -- "-z"`

Comment: thanks. please help me understand `[ "${3:-}" ]` in the code

Comment: From `man bash`: *`${parameter:-word}`: Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Your code is not correct, you missed one `]` bracket somewhere. Probably after `[ -z "$2"` block.

2) `if` statement executes following command(s) and then executes block of code enclosed in `then .. fi` or `then .. else` keywords if the return value of the command(s) is `true` (their exit code is 0)

3) `[` is just an alias for the `test` command (try `man test`). This command takes several parameters and evaluates them. For example, used with `-z "$something"` flags would return `true` (0) if `$something` is not set or is an empty string. Try it:

```
if [ -z "$variable" ]; then
    echo Variable is not set or is an empty string
fi
```

4) `||` statement is an `OR`. Next command would be executed if the previous one returned `false` statement. So in the statement

```
if [ -z "$variable" ] || [ -z "$variable2" ]; then
    echo Variable 1 or variable 2 is not set or is an empty string
fi
```

command `[ -z "$variable2" ]` would be executed only if `variable` was empty. The same could be achieved with different syntax:

```
if [ -z "$variable" -o -z "$variable2" ]; then
    echo Variable 1 or variable 2 is not set or is an empty string
fi
```

which should be faster, because it requires only one instance of the `test` program to be run. Flag `-o` means `OR`, so you could read it as:
If `variable` is not set/empty OR `variable2` is not set/EMPTY...

5) Statement `"[ ${3:-} ]"` means return `true` if `$3` (the third argument of the script) is set.

6) `>&2` is a stream redirection. Every process has two outputs: standard output and error output. These are independent and could be redirected (for example) to be written to two different files. `>&2` means "redirect standard output to the same location as standard error".

So to sum up: commands between `then .. fi` will be executed IF the script is run with `$1` empty or `$2` empty or `$3` NOT empty That means that the script should be run with exactly two parameters. And if not, the `echo` message will be printed to standard error output.

Answer (score 3):

`-z STRING` means `the length of STRING is zero`.

`${parameter:-word}` If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. In your case $3 is just set with a blank value, if $3 do not have any value.

`&2` writes to standard-error. I mean the `stdout` value of the executed command is sent to `stderr`,